# Hiding Date Field in Date Picket App Crash in Nougat OS : [Android]

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-7.0-nougat

I am using code to hide Date in Date picker. It worked fine in devices having OS less than 7.0 [Android Nougat] device.

```
((ViewGroup) dpDialog.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

No view is referenced, it returns `null`

```
findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android"))
```

Comment: Use an existing third-party widget that does what you want. Or, create your own widget. Or, fork the `DatePicker` and add the functionality that you want. "It worked fine in devices having OS less than 7.0" -- only for the few that you tested. Device manufacturers and custom ROM developers are welcome to modify `DatePicker` however they want.

Comment: Hey final solution? i facing the same issue.. Please help..

Comment: if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.NOUGAT) {
       /// Do the same thing
}

Comment: and for nougat even you hide the date its not looking good in UX, so you have Custom Widget for the Date Picker @sherl0cked

Comment: hi,,,,any solution ?

Comment: @lisha no. You have to customized your picker. Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")) This may varies for rest OS, so this is not the good way to do it.